# Using ActiveJob, perform_now seems to have different results than perform_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob

I'm using `ActiveJob` with `SideKiq` and with the code below I'm getting differing results when using `perform_later` than `perform_now`.

When using `perform_now` my code creates the specified folder and file.
When using `perform_later` I can see the code executes and doesn't get thrown into the Retry queue of Sidekiq, yet doesn't create the folder or file.

If there is anything else I could produce to help troubleshoot the issue please let me know, as I've likely just overlooked it.

**app/controllers/concerns/pdf_player_reports.rb**

```
module PdfPlayerReports
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # before_action :set_player
    # before_action :set_user_report
  end

  def director_report_pdf

    @players = Player.where(id: params["id"])

    html = render_to_string template: "players/director_summary_report.pdf.erb"
    CreatePdfJob.perform_later(html)

    #CreatePdfJob.perform_now(html)

  end

end
```

**app/jobs/create_pdf_job.rb**

```
class CreatePdfJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :high_priority

  def perform(*args)
    generate_pdf_from_string(args.first)
  end

  def generate_pdf_from_string(html)

    # create pdf from passed in HTML string
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html)

    # Create the directory for the pdfs that will be gernereated incases where it doesn't already exist
    pdf_directory_path = Rails.root.join('public','uploads','pdfs')
    unless File.directory? pdf_directory_path
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(pdf_directory_path)
    end

    # Open the specified file and then write the contents to disk
    File.open(pdf_directory_path.join('output.pdf'),'wb') do |f|
      f << pdf
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: I removed the following line from my `config/application.rb`: `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` and perform_later worked.  Now I think it's because this just causes it to run inline -- very similar if not the same as using `perform_now`.  Is it perhaps a server side issue where the sidekiq worker doesn't have the proper rights to write a folder/file to disk?

Comment: Are all of your processes running on a single machine? (i.e. is the job maybe creating your file on a different server than where you are looking?) Could also be an issue with how your passing the argument using the splat (*). Consider that when you call perform_later, the arguments for the job are being serialized and then deserialized when sidekiq runs. You may be calling .first on a string, not a list of arguments.

Comment: @AdamFinley, Same machine, also what would be the proper way of calling args to pass in my one string parameter?

Comment: `def perform(html_string)
    generate_pdf_from_string(html_string)
end`

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've tried what you've shown and still nothing. I put in some log info to the `CreatePdfJob` to see what is getting executed on the ActiveJob perform function - but none of the log messages show up in my logs. Not sure if that has something to do with the way sidekiq executes or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue (to my understanding) seems to be that I need to cancel my sidekiq process and restart it (`sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`) anytime I change code on the Job file.